# Invalid regular expression unmatched ')'

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a regex that should match email addresses and it works great here https://regex101.com/r/nBl4Wc/2, but when I try to execute it using `JavaScript` it gives this error:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression Unmatched ')'

This is my code:

```
var myString = 'email_address=test.user@gmail.com';
var regex = new RegExp('(?:[a-z0-9+_~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9+_~-]+)*)@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:+)\]');
var matched = myString.match(regex);
```

Why that regex isn't working with `JavaScript`?

I saw that there are other questions similar to this one, but I couldn't find a solution that would fix this issue...

Comment: Use the regex literal notation, `/pattern/`.

Comment: Out of interest, why reinvent the wheel? Your sample is either too strict or too lax, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that but is still not working

Comment: [It does match  your string](https://jsfiddle.net/hoorLyvu/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes it works...I didn't remove " ' " when I tried that